# How do I convert my *.py files to *.class files?

Tags: java, python, class

I need to convert [`.py`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) files to [`.class`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) files so that I can make use of my Python code in a Java environment. How do I do it?

Comment: `cp foo.py foo.class`

Comment: Jython is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jython. It has a built-in compiler to convert `.py` files to `.class`, called [jythonc](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/jythonc.html).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to integrate Python and Java is by using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).